# Select whole row of result with the highest value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a really simple question, but unfortunately I can't figure it out myself. I have a list of 12 players which all have an (unique)ID, rating, attribute1 and attribute4. I ONLY want the row of the player with the highest rating followed by attribute1 and then attribute4. So it will first have to sort on rating, if there are 2 with rating 84, SQL will check for attribute1 etc. This is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id` = $player[0] OR `id` = $player[1] OR `id` = $player[2] OR `id` = $player[3] OR `id` = $player[4] OR `id` = $player[5] OR `id` = $player[6] OR `id` = $player[7] OR `id` = $player[8] OR `id` = $player[9] OR `id` = $player[10] OR `id` = $player[11] ORDER BY `rating` DESC , `attribute1` DESC, `attribute4` DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['rating'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

I can't figure it out how to go further, as I already tryed

> SELECT MAX('rating') FROM `players_db` WHERE ...

But then it only gets the rating of the highest player, so how can I get the whole row of the player with the highest rating followed by attribute1 and attribute4?

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Add `limit 1` to your original query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OMFG worst question I ever did...

Comment: Three someones helped you out below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` , So that first it will sort the records by rating, then it will select the first row from top AS used `LIMIT 1`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id` = $player[0] OR `id` = $player[1] OR `id` = $player[2] OR `id` = $player[3] OR `id` = $player[4] OR `id` = $player[5] OR `id` = $player[6] OR `id` = $player[7] OR `id` = $player[8] OR `id` = $player[9] OR `id` = $player[10] OR `id` = $player[11] ORDER BY `rating` DESC , `attribute1` DESC, `attribute4` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['rating'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will give the record corresponding to the player with the highest rating.  In the event of a tie, `attribute1` and `attribute4` will be used to break the tie, in that order.

```
SELECT *
FROM players_db
ORDER BY rating DESC, attribute1 DESC, attribute4 DESC
LIMIT 1
```